# LSApplicationQueriesSchemes not working in custom framework

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podspec

I have an app A and custom framework F (have podspec file). Both of it have `Info.plist`. I added framework F in app A. framework F has a function which checks whether a particular app is installed in device or not

```
static func isAppPresent() -> Bool {
        let custURL : URL = URL(string: "myapp://")!
        return UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(custURL)
    }
```

When the function is called I get the error

> "error: This app is not allowed to query for scheme myapp"

given I had already added the whitelisting code in `Info.plist` of framework F

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>myobopay</string>
    </array>
```

I went through the articles but found same thing everywhere. After some time of searching I added above whitelisting code in `Info.plist` of app A and now the app was working. After some debugging I found that the whitelisting code in `Info.plist` of framework F is of no use, it is making no change keeping it there.

I dont want to share my `app scheme` with the third party user. How can I do this?

Comment: You think you need to tell iOS system that you want to query for that app scheme. You must mention that exact scheme in `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`

Comment: scheme name is correct. I copy pasted entire key value from one plist to another

Comment: Add the scheme in app info.plist rather than framework's

Comment: Thats the thing I am asking why should I do that? Assume framework is sdk kind of thing which is looking for some of its app then why should sdk creater tell the sdk user that our app can be opened like this?

Comment: It is like this. Telling the system that this app with all its frameworks integrated can "query" for this scheme. If you are using an SDK, the sdk creator will tell you to add this scheme in your info.plist because this SDK queries for this scheme in the system.

Comment: ok i got it I have to ask user to do that.. Isn't there any way using which framework's Info.plist and app's list merge at run time?

Comment: Not really sure of that.